# Angular $broadcast not working.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to share informations between two controllers with [$scope.$on](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24on) and [$scope.$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast).

Here is the view:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        {{content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controllers:

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'bidule');
}])

.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
        $scope.content = b;
    });
}])
```

and the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dOjli?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try triggering your $broadcast() from an ng-click or something. Perhaps doing it at "controller startup" is too soon for the child controller.  I'd try it but I'm on a phone, and plunkr doesn't work so well on a small device :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The child controller isn't instantiated yet. Wrapping the `broadcast` in a `timeout` works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MF7P16K1OTv46JNgkkih?p=preview

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'bidule');
});
```

Comment: This seems like a bad hack. It doesn't work unless I add a `500` ms delay in my large app.

Comment: If this is a bad hack, how does one properly solve the issue in Angular 1.x?

Comment: @jaycer refer my answer

Answer (score 9):

**Child not initiated.** Faced the same issue and this was my solution.

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('initiateEvent', function(event, b) {
        $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'bidule');
    } 
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
        $scope.content = b;
    });
    $scope.$emit('initiateEvent', null); 
}])
```

Here i'm initiating the child and asking the parent to broadcast `someEvent`

Comment: I REALLY want to like this method.  But what if I have a variable number of directives (Let's say 20... but then somebody adds one)?  Should they all `initiateEvent`, and the Parent Controller count them?  Then, when all 21 are finished, THEN broadcast?  What about when 22 is added?  The parent has to know that?  The whole point of event-driven is that pieces don't have to know other pieces exist.

Comment: @Suamere so what's your solution mate?

Answer (score 3):

To broadcast an event, you simply have to call it.

The following code works perfectly :

Your view :

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl" ng-click="myFunc()">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        {{content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and your controllers :

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() { 
        $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'bidule');
    }
}])

.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
        $scope.content = b;
    });
}])
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: i want to call $scope.myFunc from parentctrl how can i do it rather than html file