# how to pass variable from child state to a parent state AngularJs ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have in my index.htm two pages pageA.html and pageB.html.

In in app.js i used ui-router.

When my app run a java controller redierect the app to index.html where with $urlRouterProvider activated pageA by default.

So in index.html i have

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<span>{{user.name} {{user.firstname}}</span>
<a href="#pageA"><a/>
<a href="#pageB"><a/>
   <div ui-view   ></div>
</div>
```

In app.js

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/pageA');
$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url : '/home',
        views : {
            "" : {

                templateUrl : 'index.html',
                controller : 'IndexController'
            }
        }

    })
.state('pageA', {
        url : '/pageA',
        views : {
            "" : {

                templateUrl : 'pageA.html',
                controller : 'pageAController'
            }
        }

    })


    .state('pageB', {
        url : '/pageB',
        views : {
            "" : {

                templateUrl : 'pageB.html',
                controller : 'pageBController'
            }
        }

    })

});
```

I tried both in IndexController and PageAController to set the user variable:

```
$scope.user = UserService.getConnectedUser();
```

The problem is the user is not recognized in index.html.

I don't know how to pass it there ?

Update:

I tried the solution suggested:
i added in my IndexController.js

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('HomeEvent', "String"); // going down
    $scope.$on("HomeEvent", function (evt, data) {
            $scope.Message = "Inside HomeController : " + data;
    });
```

And in my PageAController.js:

```
$rootScope.$on('HomeEvent', function (event, data) {
      $scope.Message = "Inside PageAController : " + data;
        console.log("data getted ="+$scope.Message); // 'Some data'
});
```

And it doesn't even enter in $on , is am i missing something?

Comment: look at broadcast (call a function down the chain) and emit (call a function up the chain).  That is what we usually use to pass information between controllers

Comment: Thx, intersting and i tried to use it , can you see the update of my question, it doesn't enter in $on ti handler the event

Comment: i tried to use $timeout(function(){},500); in order to wait the child to be created

Comment: im sorry I didn't see your response till just now.  glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by using  broadcast (call a function down the chain) and emit (call a function up the chain) and also seting the time for broadcast  to a delay time in order to wait the creation of the child by referencing to this queestion [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075044/angular-broadcast-not-working)