# broadcast not received in controller - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a link in file that opens an other file. The second file has tabs in it. When the second file is opened from the first file, I want a particular tab to be shown.

The link from the first file is not the only way the second file is opened. So only when second file is opened from first file I want the second tab to be shown

The tabs work using an `active` class. When it has a class `active` that tab is shown.

I am trying to do this by broadcasting when the link is clicked and then routing to the second file. But it does not work.

I guess the second controller is not initialized when the first controller file broadcasts the event.

```
    <a href="#!/adminassociation" 
       ng-click="showGoverningBodyTab()">Link to second file</a>
```

On `ng-click` of this link I broadcast the event

```
$scope.showGoverningBodyTab = function(){

  $rootScope.$broadcast('displayGoverningBody', {data: null});
}
```

In the second file:

```
  $timeout($scope.$on('displayGoverningBody', function(){
    console.log("broadcast");
    $('#myassociation').removeClass('active');
    $('#documentregistry').removeClass('active');
    $('#governingmembers').addClass('active');
  }));
```

I don't see the `console.log` either.

**Edit**: It worked when I used the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075410/10114001) on the controller that broadcasts the event

Comment: dont add `$scope.$on` function inside a `$timeout` function

Comment: @azad still doesn't work

Comment: is the console out put comes/

Comment: @azad no .. it does not show

Comment: @azad I think the second controller is not initialized when the first controller broadcasts.

Comment: the second controller should be a child controller of first controller

Comment: @azad i used `rootScope`. so i guess it doesn't have to be a child?